# Python Flask Service file is not starting

Tags: linux, python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi, uwsgi

I wrote a small app.  The app works great.  However I am trying to create a service file and I am running into issues.  Running the command `sudo uwsgi uwsgi.ini` works.  App starts up.
I created a service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=uWsgi instance to start relay site
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/relay
ExecStart=sudo uwsgi uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service file errors when I try to start it.

```
Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
relay.service: Unit entered failed state.
relay.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[/etc/systemd/system/relay.service:11] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: uwsgi uwsgi.ini
relay.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
[/etc/systemd/system/relay.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: sudo uwsgi uwsgi.ini
relay.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `Executable path is not absolute` because the executable is `sudo` and not `/usr/bin/sudo`. Systemd needs the full path because it does not use a shell as you do when you use a terminal.

Also, if you're going to `sudo` the command then you might as well use `root` as the user instead (which is the default). Something like this should work:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/relay
ExecStart=/absolute/path/to/uwsgi uwsgi.ini
```

You can run `which uwsgi` to find the absolute path to `uwsgi`.

Comment: Thanks for the help and info.